# How come I got the tenacious badge

Tags: support, badges, zero-score-badges

Well, I have been [awarded the Tenacious badge](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/badges/34/tenacious?userid=107479) an hour ago... But I don't think I actually deserve it (even though it's nice to get badges).

As I understand, I need more than 5 accepted answers with zero score. Fine, I have 6 of them. But it needs to represent more than 20% of my total answers, am I right? Well, I have a total of 97 answers which is much more than the 30 limit the math gives (unless I'm missing something).

*Edit:* Ok a comment explained it was 20% out of *accepted* answers. So first, I felt stupid. Then I counted, and I have 36 accepted answers. We got closer, but still not in specs, right?

Comment: It must be 20% of *accepted* answers.

Comment: @Chenmunka Thanks. However, I have 36 accpeted answers... Still strange?

Comment: Self-answers and community wiki answers don't count either, do you have any of them?

Comment: @Glorfindel No, I don't have any of those.

Comment: Maybe one of the 36 doesn't count for reasons unknown, and one of your +1 accepted answers was just recently upvoted (after the badge was awarded)? That would make it 7 out of 35 which is just the limit for Tenacious.

Comment: Here is a query that works https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1228150/how-unsung-am-i-fixed-ver-includes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As described [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions), there are additional criteria for the Tenacious and Unsung Hero badges:

- Only accepted answers at least ten days old are considered
- Community wiki answers, deleted answers, and self-accepted answers are not included in any calculations

In your case only the first applies, and removes your recent nine answers from the calculations.

Earlier today (about one hour before you got the badge) [this answer of yours](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/240550/gates-and-energy-loss/240555#240555) which is accepted and with zero score, became exactly ten days old, causing you to  have 6 out of 29 zero scored accepted answers, which answers all the conditions. So this 20.7% was just enough to  give you the badge.

Wear it proudly! :)

Comment: Thanks. Well, I will wear it proudly, now that I know I actually deserved it (by a hair, apprently, though).

Comment: No probs @Dim. You can always imagine further how far you're from Unsung hero. Certainly more than a hair. :P